# Programming for the SAE J1939 standard

Tags: mobile, embedded, can-bus, canopen, iec61131-3

I'm trying to find information on how to program an embedded mobile controller such as the [ifm R 360](http://www.can-cia.org/pg/canopen/profiles/405/ifm/ifm2/index.html). Where could I find specific information on the programming language used, the required development environment and any other useful information?

From what I understand, the programming language is based on IEC 61131-3. What books or tutorials should I look at to better understand this?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a [J1939 Software Protocol Stack](http://www.simmasoftware.com/j1939.html)

Comment: I am using this very stack.  Great support and very efficient code.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently you need a version of [CoDeSys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CoDeSys) adapted to the controllers, see the [products page](http://www.ifm-electronic.com/ifmus/web/padv1!US_4_10_10_10_60_10_30.html).